# Include sterling symbol in xtable

Tags: r, knitr

I'm failing to figure out how to include valid `£` sign into `knitr` document. It keeps appearing as `L` alphabet.

Sample data:

```
require(xtable)

df <- data.frame(x=seq(1,10,1),y=rnorm(10))
colnames(df) <- c("ID",paste("VALUE IN","\u00A3",sep=" "))

Xtab <- xtable(df, digits=0, caption="\\textbf{MINIMAL/IDEAL}")
align(Xtab) <- c( "l|","c","p{0.9in}") 

print(Xtab, size = "small")
```

So far so good, R prints the `£` sign correctly into the R console. However it fails to show correctly in the generated `pdf` document.

I also included `encoding` but problem remains. I read about double escaping but the `£` sign if double escaped appears as `\\u00A3` in document.

```
knit("file.Rmd", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

**EDIT**: If I just include `paste("VALUE IN","€",sep=" ")` it works but not with if I replace the `€` with `£` as this shows up as `L` alphabet. Why is this?

Comment: what about using `\mathsterling` or `\textsterling` instead

Comment: @rawr: thanks, I tried but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @RHertel: thanks, but these as @rawr provided would be helpful if one would have different procedure. I have a *.Rmd file, where the above example I provided goes into the `r chunk` etc. Esentially I have the column name od data.frame a sterling symbol there, this doesn't work LaTeX-wise.

Comment: Oh, yes! I'm also using RStudio with default UTF-8 encoding so this may explain why the encoding did not work since I used encodind twice, essentially chancelling encoding altogether :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it works with the following for me:

```
paste("VALUE IN",sep=" ",`Encoding<-`("£", "UTF8"))
```

Hence direct embedded encoding. Interestingly (for me) if you run the above in R console it shows as `L` alphabet but in the rendered document it shows correctly as sterling `£`.